# Memory Impact on Sending Binary File through HTTP PUT in PHP without multipart/form-data

Tags: php, file-upload

I recently wrote a code where I send a normal PUT request which has contents of a binary file in the request body with the `Content-Type` header set to the mime type of said file. In the server, I handle that by just reading the raw request body in a variable, employing some validation: size (using `strlen`) and mime types (using `finfo->buffer`) and then copying the contents to a file (using `file_put_contents`).

The usual (or popular, I guess) way of uploading files would be using `multipart/form-data` encoding, which would be handled automatically by PHP. In that case, PHP would write the contents in a temporary file, which I believe exists in a storage device rather than memory.

Now, I went through the code in https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/rfc1867.c , and it seemed to put the request body in memory anyways.

My question is:

0) Does PHP store the full request body in memory (at least once), regardless of the `enctype` it gets?

1) Does getting all the raw body and writing it to a file (using `file_put_contents`) uses more memory compared to using php's internal `multipart/form-data` handling mechanism to upload a file?

1a) Does php's [copy-on-write](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/zvals/memory_management.html#reference-counting-and-copy-on-write) mechanism help me here? that is to say am I allocating new blocks of memory when I store the raw body content in some variable (and not a file)? Or am I just pointing to the request data that is already on the memory (if there is) ?

2) If what I'm doing does impact memory, do you have any suggestions for improvement that does not involve using `multipart/form-data` ?

PS: I do not need to send anything else (e.g., metadata) with the file, nor do I have the need to send multiple files in a single request.

PPS: Sorry if my post is incomprehensible, I'd be happy to provide other details if anything seems confusing or incomplete.

**EDIT**

- Added Question 0.
- Slightly Modified questions in hopes of making it less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Does getting all the raw body and writing it to a file (using file_put_contents makes me use more memory rather than letting PHP handle it?

Yeah, tons.  With `file_put_contents()` alone, you need the full data in-memory before writing it.  It's meant for more of a utility for small files and such.

> 1a) Does php's copy-on-write mechanism help me here? that is to say am I allocating new blocks of memory when I store the raw body content in some variable (and not a file)?

I'm not familiar with specifically what you're referring to, but yes if you store the body content in a variable, a copy of it is sitting in memory.

> 2) If what I'm doing does impact memory, do you have any suggestions for improvement that does not involve using multipart/form-data ?

Yes!  Check out the `php://input` stream.  This will allow you to access the raw POST body.

http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I think I failed to convey my curiosities in those questions, and thus I've modified the original post. I was actually interested on knowing the difference between letting php write to a temporary file vs writing to a file myself. Upon further peeking at the php-src, I think I'm better off writing to a file myself rather than using php's internal mechanism.

Comment: 1a) It depends. `$copyOfBigThing = $bigThing;` Yes. But having a massive blob of data sitting in `$_POST` instead of having PHP write it to a tempfile, of course not.

Comment: @cipher PHP does not keep the whole request in RAM past a certain point, and definitely does not keep entire file uploads in-memory. You can test that yourself by uploading a file larger than the amount of memory installed in your server. You're going in the opposite direction of everything Brad and I have said so far.